# Does kaaproject.org have any solution to support udp transport between endpoint and operation server?

Tags: kaa

From the open source code of `AbstractKaaClient.java` below, i'm sure kaaproject supports TCP protocol between endpoint and kaa server.

```java
KaaDataChannel operationsChannel = new DefaultOperationTcpChannel(
kaaClientState, failoverManager, failureListener);
```

But there are some cases, especially in IoT domain, UDP is more popular than TCP, for its bigger transport overheads. Does kaaproject.org have any plan to support udp transport ?  If it has already supported, could you please give me a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported in 0.x versions of KAA platform. But in 1.0 version we planned to add support for CoAP that built over UDP.